How do you score 5 5 5 6 7? In cribbage
Scoring a run using strips in cribbage

Fifteen-two;
Pair Royal of 6 for 8;
Triple run of three is nine for 17.
This ordering is standard, and helps both avoid confusion and omissions.
Cribbage Scoring
